# a large amount of the population speaks/speak?

Tags: agreement

Can you say "a large amount of the population" or should it be "a large number of the population?
And if you CAN say "a large amount of the population" is this amount considered singular or plural?

Comment: 'A large _number_ of the population are in favour of ...'. 'Amount' is neither logical nor colloquial. And 'number' takes the plural.

Comment: "A large proportion ..." or "A large segment ..." or "A large fraction ..." would be more idiomatic.